# A Question About Proposition 18.1.1 in Convex Analysis

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

> THEOREM 18.1. Let $C$ be a convex set, and let $C^{\prime}$ be a face of $C$. If $D$ is a convex set in $C$ such that $ri D$ meets $C^{\prime}$, then $D \subset C^{\prime}$.

> Corollary 18.1.1. If $C^{\prime}$ is a face of a convex set $C$, then $C^{\prime}=$ $C \cap \mathrm{cl} C^{\prime}$. In particular, $C^{\prime}$ is closed if $C$ is closed.

> Proof. Take $D=C \cap \mathrm{cl} C^{\prime}$.

If $ri C \cap ri (cl C')\neq\varnothing$, i can compelte understand the proof. But,I have a question, if $ri C \cap ri (cl C')=\varnothing$, how to prove?

Comment: What is $riD$???

Comment: Can you please define "face" more specifically, because it is not a standard term! This theorem appears in many books as the definition of a face. So give the definition of "face" that you use!

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Sorry, I was busy with other things and didn't see your comment. $ri D$ is the relative interior point in the Convex Analysis book.

Comment: relative to what?

Comment: we consider in $\mathbb{R}^n$, and relative to $\text{aff}(D)$

Answer (score 1):

Let $y$ be in $D$ . We know that $C'\subseteq rbdC$.

the relative boundary of $C$. Since there is a $x\in riD\bigcap C'$,

we have $x\in rbdC$.  If $\,\,y\in riC$ then $[y,x]\subseteq\,C$. But

$x\in\,riD$ so there is some $a>1$ such that $(1-a)y+ax\,\in\,D$ but

not in $C$. Contradiction, since $riD\,\subseteq\,C$. Thus, $y\in rbdC$ and hence it belongs to one of the faces. If it belongs to a

face other than $C'$ there is a point $ay+(1-a)x$ $\in riC$ , and we

apply the previous argument for this point. So , $y$ has to be on face

$C'$, which completes the proof!!

Comment: Sorry, I was busy with other things and didn't see your comment.  But is it possible that $ri D \cap C'$ is an empty set?

Comment: I know that if $\operatorname{riC} \cap \operatorname{ri}\left(c l C^{\prime}\right)\neq\varnothing$,  then we have $ri D=ri C\cap ri C'$, and then we can use theorem 18.1. But if $\operatorname{riC} \cap \operatorname{ri}\left(c l C^{\prime}\right)=\varnothing$,  i can not prove...

Comment: No, it is not possible, because $riD\bigcap\,C'$ is nonempty by assumption!! I look forward to an upvote!

Comment: Thanks, I have upvoted it. But I still have a question, I don't see $ri D\cap C'\neq\varnothing$ from the conditions of the proposition, can you elaborate more?

Comment: It is one of the assumptions of the Theorem, second line!! Thanks!

Comment: Umm，this is a problem with my statement. The D in the Theorem is different from the D in the Corollary proof. Proof in the Corollary is to assume a set $D$ called "$C\cap clC'$"

Comment: But I am not using the proof. I prove the theorem directly!!

Comment: oh, sorry, is my understanding wrong? I took a serious look at your conclusion: "Let y be in D", "then   has to be on face C'", you seem to be proving Theorem 18.1?  But I mainly want to ask about Corollary 18.1.1............QAQ

Answer (score 0):

Proof of the Corollary $18.1.1$ First

$C'\subseteq C\bigcap \,clC'$.

If
$x\in C'$ then , by definition $x\in\,C$ and clearly $x\in\,C'\,\subseteq\,clC' $.

Now we prove the inverse. $C\,\bigcap\,clC'\,\subseteq\,C'$.

Assume that $x\in C$ and $x\in clC'$. If $x\,\notin C'$, then

$x\,\in\,rbd\,C'$, and hence $x\in\,rbd\,C$. Now we notice

that $x\in\,C$ implies either $x\,\in riC$ which is a

contradiction (since $x\in\,rbdC$) or belongs to one of the faces.

Assume that it belongs to a face $D$' other than $C'$.

Then there are two possibilities , either

$x\,\in\,D'\bigcap C'$ or the distance $d(x,C')$ is positive.

In the first case $x\,\in\,C'$ contradiction.

In the second case we have $d(x,C')>0$, while $x\,$ in $clC'$ contradiction.

Therefore our initial assumption that $x\notin\,C'$ was false,

i.e. $x\,\in\,C'$